# ‘Tensor’ object has no attribute ‘reshape’

Tags: reshape, theano, tensor

I am working with Masked Conditional Neural Networks, in the field of audio classification. I am trying to reshaping a tensor in the following way

```
concatenated_segments = mini_batch.reshape((segment_count * segment_length, feature_count))
```

but I get the following error:

```
‘Tensor’ object has no attribute ‘reshape’
```

I have also tried to use, as suggested elsewhere, the following

```
concatenated_segments = T.reshape(mini_batch, (segment_count * segment_length,feature_count))
```

where T stands for: `import theano` and `from theano import tensor as T`.  However, this does not solve the problem, since it gets the error

```
Cannot convert (Dimension(None), Dimension(256)) to TensorType', <class 'tuple'>
```

I am using Theano

For further details, I am trying to understand and run the code from the publication *Masked Conditional Neural Networks for Audio Classification*. The code is available here: [GitHub-Repo](https://github.com/fadymedhat/MCLNN). All the library versions match the Git description. The above line is in the *Layer.py* module.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the tensorflow version https://github.com/fadymedhat/MCLNN. This has more updated libraries.